# what's the system account to run asp.NET web app for each sites in IIS with different application pool?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Suppose I have many different website created on IIS 7 on windows 2008 R2.
Each of them may have different application pool:

```
.NET 1.1
.NET 2.0
.NET 3.5
.NET 4.0
```

What the system account to run all those web app? If the app need to read/write file, need to set up right permission for specific folder, then how can I identify the right account to assign right permission?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If it's IIS 7, it's *probably* going to be whatever the identity of the AppPool is. There are many exceptions to this rule, all of which depend on circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Identity of each one of the application pools by using a unique account for each and then set the permissions appropriately. Hope this helps.